# Is there a solid howto for replacing MySQL with Maria in the LAMP stack?

Tags: 10.04, server, 11.10, mysql

I've heard great feedback on a few folks migrating production machines (including from [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/299361/has-anyone-migrated-production-machines-from-mysql-to-mariadb)), and I'd like to test the transition in our dev environment. Maria is apparently in the 11.10 repos, but there has to be more to it than just apt-get install; what else needs to be done to switch it out? Do the php5-mysql libraries work out-of-the proverbial box?

A quick google didn't turn up anything, so I was hoping someone could either point me to a good article, or lay out the steps in an answer here.

Comment: FYI, maria did not make it into the 11.10 repos due to time constraints. It may land in 12.04.. but either way, upstream's packages (see Mark D's answer) should work fine.

Comment: http://i1053.photobucket.com/albums/s471/curious_apprentice/Ubuntu/Screenshotat2012-05-01074944.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article/tutorial may be of some help.

http://kb.askmonty.org/en/building-mariadb-on-ubuntu

According to Monty, (the creator), all php mysql libraries should work without any changes.

Comment: Thanks! This looks helpful for building, but I was hoping for something more in depth in the line of replacing binaries, installing, config differences, etc.